# HTML array multiply javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code

```
<input name="itemCode[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemCode" tabindex="1"/> </td>
<input name="itemDesc[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemDesc"  readonly="readonly" /></td>
<input name="itemQty[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemQty" tabindex="2" onchange="multiply(this)"/></td>
<input name="itemPrice[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemPrice" readonly="readonly" /> </td>
```

Javascript code

```
function multiply(el) {
   var i= el.value * document.getElementById('itemPrice').value;
   document.getElementById('itemPrice').value =i;
}
```

Problem is this:
the first row in the table multiplies correctly but the second row doesn't work....please help

Comment: How do you know that the first row is correct while the second one is incorrect?

Comment: IDs must be **unique**! Search for it, this has been explained so many, many times.

Comment: You don't show an element with id of "item", so the first line of the function won't work. And further to what Felix said, this seems to be in a table row, so if you've repeated that on many rows with the same ids repeated it won't work properly - `.getElementById()` will return only the first one (or, for certain browsers, possibly the last one).

Comment: I don't any ANY "item" field...

Comment: are you missing every opening `<td>` from the real markup too?

Comment: Regarding your updated code, setting the 'itemPrice' field to _itself_ multiplied by the quantity is a bad idea, because if the user changes the quantity again it will be multiplied by 'itemPrice' as calculated for the previous quantity, not the original unit price.

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KuC2z/1/

Comment: @jbabey, yes, but OP has multiple rows of inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/KuC2z/3/

Comment: @irrelephant then he has multiple elements with the same ID and this question should be closed as one of the many duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you cannot identify the row correctly with `itemXxxxx` alone.
It's better to use some id to identify the "row" you are referring to.

For example something like (for *every* row, in this case row/item no. 23):

```
<input id="price23" .....>
<input id="qty23" ......>
<input id="total23" onchange="calc(23);" ...>
```

function `calc(id)` is:

```
function calc(id)
{

     var p = document.getElementById("price"+id).value;
     var q = document.getElementById("qty"+id).value;
     document.getElementById("total"+id).value = p * q;
}
```

It is easy to inject row number from some serverside code.

Edit: Another option would be using JQuery with some DOM traversals between parents and siblings to get the desired values.

Comment: but i dont know how many row will b there it is some thing like this
http://www.codemashups.com/source/jquery/jquery-autocomplete-p1/